# Time consuming write process of Spark Dataset into the Oracle DB using JDBC driver

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Apache Spark for dataset loading,processing,and outputting the dataset into the Oracle DB using JDBC driver.

I am using spark jdbc write method for writing the Dataset into Database.
But,meanwhile writing the Dataset into the DB it takes same time for writing 10 rows and 10 Million rows into the different tables of the Database.
I want to know how to performance tune this write method using spark,so that we can make wise use of the apache spark compute engine.Otherwise,there is no benefit in using it for fast computation process;if it takes time to write the dataset into the Database.
The code to write the 10 rows and 10M rows is as follows:

## with 10 rows to write

```
 finalpriceItemParamsGroupTable.distinct().write().mode("append").format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", CI_PRICEITEM_PARM).save();
```

## with 10M rows to write

`finalPritmOutput.distinct().write().mode("append").format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", CI_TXN_DTL).save();`

Attaching the screenshot of the apache spark Dashb
oard [Spark Stages Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82XJq.png)

If some can help out would be helpful...

Answer (score 3):

You can bulk insert the records at once rather than inserting 1000 records (default setting) at a time by adding a new option batchSize and increasing its value

```
   finalPritmOutput.distinct().write()
     .mode("append")
     .format("jdbc").option("url", connection)
     .option("dbtable", CI_TXN_DTL)
     .option("batchsize", "100000")
     .save()
```

Refer to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases on how to configure your jdbc for better performance.

Comment: I added above batchsize option in the command but still I am getting the same time to write into DB..Anything more to be done to resolve this issue.

Comment: @user9207408 could you provide the images of your executors page and jobs page ? I would like to look at if the tasks ran in parallel or not.

Comment: I see that two tasks took longer time and this usually occurs when a particular partition has more values compared to other. All I could think of here is to perform coalesce on finalPritmOutput and the the input for coalesce operation you could give the num-executors *  num-cores.

Comment: @user9207408 Can you please check this issue and tell me solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151363/not-able-to-write-spark-dataset-to-database-using-jdbc